# React cannot find exported renderRoutes function

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I am working on my first meteor/react application and I am trying to use react-router. However, when I try to run the app, I can't seem to import the renderRoutes function.

I am trying to follow along with the router part here:

https://guide.meteor.com/react.html

The router lives in `myapp/client/lib/router.js`. Here is my router code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import {Home} from '../home/home.js';
import {Login} from '../login/login.js';
import {Connect} from '../connect/connect.js';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route exact path="/connect" component={Connect}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

I have a meteor.startup() function in `myapp/server/main.js`, this is all I have in there:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from '../client/lib/router.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('App'));
});
```

When I try to run `meteor run`, here's what I see:

`Error: Cannot find module '../client/lib/router.js'`

Why? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your router is located in

myapp/**client**/lib/router.js

whereas your main file is located in

myapp/**server**/main.js

So unless you intend to implement server-side-rendering, you may move the second code to

myapp/**client**/main.js

This is due to Meteor's project-structure awareness. If a file is contained in a folder, named `client` or `server` it will only be available in this environment.

More to read in the guide: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories